# Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare() Issue

Tags: plugins, upgrade, wpdb

I'm having to update a WP installation for a community organisations from version 2.9.1 to the current 3.9.1.

The installation has a couple of custom built plugins that aren't documented.

I've just performed the WP version update and now I see a warning (Missing argument 2 for `wpdb::prepare()`) on every page that relates to the following line in the code of one of these custom built plugin:

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM ".$table_name));
```

From what I've read online, this is due to a change in the coding, that requires 2 values to be sent to `wpdb::prepare()`, but I've no idea how the line of code given above, needs to be changed.

If someone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was not exactly change in code, that was change to better inform people they are not using the method correctly.

In line with [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) documentation you need to properly pass values, or they won't be properly escaped in query.

In your case it would turn into something like:

```
$wpdb->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM %s", $table_name)
```

Note that if `$table_name` isn't coming from any untrusted input, then there is no need to prepare query in *such* case altogether.

Comment: Ive change the line in question to:  $rows = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM %s", $table_name));  But now it doesnt appear to be pukking out any results.

Comment: @PhillHealey that's probably because it's table name and not just a string, quotes issues, etc. As per answer unless table name somehow comes from untrusted source you don't _need_ to prepare/escape it in first place.

Comment: So an 'unprepared' statement would look like....  $rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id, name FROM ".$table_name); ???

Comment: That seems to be working. anyway.